# Forms not found by autoloader in Zend module?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, module, zend-autoloader

I'm getting pretty fed up with Zend's autoloader.

I'm trying to load `EditPassword` from within `PasswordController` in the module structure as shown below.

[image: project structure]

application.ini

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"  
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
```

Bootstrap.php:

```
public function init() {
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
    $baseUrl = $config->baseHttp;
    define('BASE_URL', $baseUrl);
}

protected function _initAutoload() {
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('App_');
    //
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . 'modules/account',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                    'form' => array(
                            'path' => 'forms',
                            'namespace' => 'Form'))));
    $autoLoader->pushAutoloader($moduleLoader);
    //
    return $autoLoader;
}
```

I'm loading the form in the controller like this:

```
$form = new Account_Form_EditPassword();
$this->view->form = $form;
```

The error itself is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Account_Form_EditPassword' not found in 
Z:\dat\docs\workspace\metamusic\application\modules\account\controllers\PasswordController.php
on line 7
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything else in Zend seems to run off fairly sane defaults - do I really have to declare *all* the paths to forms/models/viewhelpers for each module, given that they're following the default Zend structure, and in the default modules directory?

Comment: Update your question with how you load the form in your controller

Comment: Have done. Pretty sure that's OK though, I'm using the command line tool to create form templates, and auto-complete fills in the correct name.

Comment: That looks good. Sorry, but then what is the exact error you get?

Comment: I've updated the question, but the error's not very descriptive, I'm afraid.

Comment: spelling of 'account' is misspelled in bootstraper its 'acount' one 'c' is missing .

Comment: Thanks. Not the cause of the error apparently, so I've modified to question to clarify.

Comment: What David Weinraub said is correct and should solve your problem. The convention is to setup module autoloaders in the *module* bootstrap, and Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap does this by default. So all you need to do is create a bootstrap class for your account module and then you can remove the $moduleLoader stuff from your main bootstrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would remove all the module autoloading code from the app Bootstrap and then implement an empty module bootstrap in `application/modules/account/Bootstrap.php`:

```
class Account_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}
```

Then in `application/configs/application.ini`, add the following:

```
resources.modules[] =
```

The idea here is that `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` automatically registers a resource autoloader with bunch of common path/namespace mappings, including the one for forms that you are using.

Comment: Do I have to declare that bootstrap somewhere? I've tried as you suggest, but the initSomething() functions within it are not getting called, as if Zend is unaware of its presence.

Comment: Aaah, you probably have to enable the modules in `application.ini`. Updating the answer.

Comment: Hey make sure you have both of the following lines   `resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"` and `resources.modules[] = `  in your application.ini, I had to add the frontController line to get this to work.

Comment: Very helpful! I'm amazed that zendtool doesn't automatically create a bootstrap file. I was scratching my head for hours as to why I could load controllers/views but not models/forms etc.

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap.php**

`'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . 'modules/acount'`

Should be:

`'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . 'modules/account'`

Everything else looks ok

Answer (score 0):

If this a copy/paste from your actual config then you have a typo in `'modules/acount'`

```
'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . 'modules/acount',
```

Depending on your ZF version you don't even need the autoloader in the bootstrap. You can remove it. The following in your ini does the same.

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

Comment: Thanks for the continued input. I've fixed that, but to no avail. I'm using the latest stable (1.11), so presumably that line in the ini was counteracting my typo.

Comment: @danH I'd say it's the other way around your initAutoload() is counteraction the iniconfig. Have you removed the autoloader in the bootstrap?

Comment: Yep, no luck. Removed absolutely everything else in the bootloader just to be sure, but no change. Thank you for your help by the way, it's much appreciated.